# Is it possible to restrict user/role access to TFS by file extension?

Tags: tfs, access-control, role-based-access-control

My searches are turning up many useless results, so I am hoping someone here might know off hand.  I would like to configure Team Foundation Server so that some members of a team (front end people) can only have write access on .cshtml, .css, .js files (etc) and the back-end developers can have write access on anything.  Is this possible?

Comment: No, it's not, unless you change the permissions on each file individually. This sort of thing is easier to fix by offering to fire a front-end person who changes a .cs file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. I personally also do not find it advisable, since it seriously hampers collaboration between team members. If you want go forward in this direction, then setup the solution structure to have folders for separate types of files. These folders are easily secureable.

Comment: I agree, but I'm thinking about it in terms of an organization that already has a pretty severe separation of these things such that the front-end developers can't even access the solution at all (instead they save HTML and JS to a database and that content is loaded dynamically by decision made in the C#).  I thought perhaps an extension-based access control might sit better than a full integration of teams.  The folder suggestion is good though.  Perhaps it would be harder to keep up with, but MVC projects, for instance, come out of the box with the appropriate folders for this approach.